# What are the risks of developing geoengineering?

Tags: climate-change, carbon-cycle, forest, geoengineering, light

[Wikipedia page for geoengineering entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_engineering#Proposed_strategies) list a lot of proposals to decrease global temperature:

> **Solar radiation management** methods[5] may include:
>
> - Surface-based: for example, surface-based mirror infrastructures,[29]    protecting or expanding polar sea ice and
>   glaciers, including the use    of insulating blankets or artificial
>   snow,[30][31] using pale-colors    for roofing materials and other
>   man-made surfaces (i.e. roadways and    exterior paints), attempting
>   to change the oceans' brightness,    growing high-albedo crops, or by
>   distributing hollow glass beads in    selected areas to increase ice
>   coverage and lower temperatures.[32]
> - Troposphere-based: for example, marine cloud brightening, which would    spray fine sea water to whiten clouds and thus increase cloud
>   reflectivity.
> - Upper atmosphere-based: creating reflective aerosols,    such as    stratospheric sulfate aerosols, specifically designed
>   self-levitating aerosols,[33] or other substances.
> - Space-based: space    sunshade – obstructing solar radiation with    space-based mirrors,    dust,[34] etc.
>
> **Carbon dioxide removal**
>
> - Creating biochar (i.e. in biomass-fired thermal power plants), for    mixing into the soil to create terra preta
> - Bio-energy with carbon capture and storage to sequester carbon and    simultaneously provide energy Carbon air capture to remove carbon
>   dioxide from ambient air
> - Afforestation, reforestation and forest restoration to absorb carbon    dioxide
> - Ocean afforestation and ocean fertilization (which includes iron    fertilization of the oceans)

Why have none of these methods been implemented?

What are the risks of developing geoengineering?

Comment: The lack of political will & the lack of money. All of the solar management "proposals" are just ideas. I can think of numerous reasons for each, why nothing has been done about them. As for CO2 removal, some of those have been tried on a small scale: biochar, CO2 sequestration & afforestation & reforestation. Two examples of CO2 sequestration that I'm aware of  have been failures: one test done by the CSIRO in western Victoria, Australia & an ongoing example of the [Barrow Island](https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2020-09-19/angus-taylor-carbon-capture-storage-gorgon-chevron/12676732).

Comment: For the solar management ideas, there is a large issue of risk and governance. The risks are around unintended consequences and unanticipated feedbacks. To achieve worthwhile effects these would be very large scale interventions. Changes that might moderate warming for one country or region's benefit might cause negative consequences elsewhere. An added issue is that solar management options don't address acidification of oceans at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### We don't know, and that's why we have to develop it.

that's the thing about undeveloped sciences **we don't know what many of the risks are**, Its a case of knowing what we don't know. Which is one big reason to develop it, so we don't cause harm accidentally.

Lets be clear **we already are geoengineering** right now, by driving cars, changing the landscape, polluting the air,  we are just doing it blind. We have to research things to understand the risks, and geoengineering has barely be scratched.